# php pdo double query, could/should i use a join?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have created a function to draw data from a table and display it in html using the `printf()` function. the first query pulls data from the comments table. specifically it pulls the comment post id. I then use this id to run a second query to pull the title of said post from the posts table.

is it possible/would it be better to do one single query where I do some sort of a join? I don't know much about joins hence asking. Here's the code:

```
function display_comments_table(){
    global $connect;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $stmt = $connect->link->query($sql);

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        $comment_id = $row["comment_id"];
        $comment_author = $row["comment_author"];
        $comments = $row["comment_content"];
        $comment_post_id = $row["comment_post_id"];
        $comment_email = $row["comment_email"];
        $comment_status = $row["comment_status"];
        $comment_date = date('F j, Y \a\t g:ia', strtotime( $row["comment_date"] ));

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $comment_post_id";
        $stmt2 = $connect->link->query($sql2);
        while($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()){$post_title = $row2["post_title"];}

        $comment_table = "<tr>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td>%s</td>
                            <td><a href='#'>Approve</a></td>
                            <td><a href='#'>Dispprove</a></td>
                            <td><a href='#'>Delete</a></td>
                          </tr>";

        printf("{$comment_table}",$comment_id,$comment_author,$comments,$comment_email,$comment_status,$post_title,$comment_date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `JOIN` would be much more efficient. Change your query like so:

```
SELECT c.comment_id, 
       c.comment_author, 
       c.comment_content,
       c.comment_post_id,
       c.comment_email,
       c.comment_status,
       c.comment_date,
       p.post_title
FROM comments c
JOIN posts p ON p.post_id = c.comment_post_id
```

You will be able to access the comment variables as you currently are and the post title in `$row["post_title"]`.

Note that for `JOIN`ed tables (and as good practice in general), you should explicitly list the columns you are fetching so as to avoid possible overlap in column names affecting the output results.